# how to start on using DataTable in Jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

I am trying to learn Java and Javascript. Currently I following MVC, where i have servlets that will send data from a table to a JSP and I disply the data in table.

i am trying to make this table editable and create a good look and feel of the table using DataTable, however i am not sure how or where to start..Can someone please help me on this. I am a beginner and any simple example on on how to use DataTable would really help?

Thank you!

Comment: Why does this have jquery in the title but not in the tags or question?

Comment: [JQuery datatable](http://datatables.net/).

Answer (score 2):

There are several examples here: http://datatables.net/examples/

Datatables is a great plugin if you want to show the data. But in my experience, it is not simple to interact with the server.. Like... add a new tr and create an instance on database using java. It is complicated this interaction.

In my experience, I would use primefaces datables: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableBasic.jsf;jsessionid=1si9n7bh9e6921gz0mj3w42ew3

Comment: Thanks! I will try prime faces. But on the datatables - I have seen the example on the websit, I was not sure what file I  have to include in my HTML page header to make it work?

Comment: You have to download the dependences... check this out: http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html ... then just follow the examples.

There are more examples here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableHome.jsf